# Turbo boost is on even when CPU utilization is at 0 percent

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, central-processing-unit, xeon

My new server is behaving strangely, it seems that turbo boost is always on even when there's no utilization. The OS is windows server 2012 r2 and power option is set to balanced with default BIOS settings. I have never seen this problem on any of my servers before. what could be the problem?

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v3 @ 2.60GHz

Maximum speed:  2.60 GHz
Sockets:    1
Cores:  8
Logical processors: 16
Virtualization: Enabled
L1 cache:   512 KB
L2 cache:   2.0 MB
L3 cache:   20.0 MB

Utilization 0%
Speed   2.78 GHz
```